# Search an array in other array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have 2d array,
Here is my array;

```
 public string[,,,] cars = new string[,,,]
{
    {
        { { "JOY", "Motor 1", "kırmızı", "link1" } },
        { { "JOY", "Motor 1", "mavi", "link" } },
        { { "JOY", "Motor 1", "siyah", "link" } },
        { { "JOY", "Motor 1", "gri", "link" } },
        { { "TOUCH", "Motor 1", "gri", "link" } }
    }
};
```

and 1d array,

```
  string[] selectedCar = new string[] { "JOY", "Motor 1", "gri" };
```

What I want to do is, I want to search the selectedCar array in the cars array and return the link which is the last elements of cars array.

Thanks in advance ^^

Comment: what have you tried? :)

Comment: but it wouldn't be the last  ... it would be the 4th I guess? ... does the order matter? What if there are multiple matches? Why is `cars` a 4d array? And not simply an array of arrays or 2d array?

Comment: re the Unity tag, though you may be inside a Unity 3D environment, array are the realm of C#.   Unity doesn't change anything.

Comment: cars array is just to create a kind of local database which I will use for customizing cars and redirecting the links. And selectedCar array will be user preferences. (@rusttBusketBay , it is also the answer to your question ^_^ )

Comment: still why does your array have 4 dimensions? For the data you show here `string[,]` would be enough ... even easier might be you have a proper class `Car` with different actual fields you can filter on .. e.g. show all that have `cars.Where(c => c.Motor == "Motor 1").ToArray();` etc

Comment: if each array is a car, why not create a car object, and store the cars in the array, this way it would be simpler to filter.

Comment: I don't know why I thought that it have to be 4d  :'

Comment: For me it is not entirely clear what you want to achieve. Perhaps you can edit your question and add the desired output. Then we can think of a piece of code to produce that output given the input you have already clearly stated :).

Comment: @derHugo I tried it before and I got an error. Here is that: string[*,*]' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no accessible extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'string[*,*]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @justA well the `Where` example refers to `even easier might be you have a proper class Car with different actual fields you can filter on` were you wold have a simple `Car[]` like in the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simplify this I would create an Car class like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class car {
   public string prop1;
   public string prop2;
   public string prop3;
   public string prop4;
}
```

and then just have a simple array or list of cars:

```
car[] cars = new car[]{...}
```

this way you just can use linq to filter:

```
car res = cars.Where(x => x.prop1 == "value").First();
```

and now you can get any property of the filtered car.

You will need to add

```
using System.Linq;
```

on top of your script

Comment: just changed the class to make it serializable in the Unity Inspector .. now you can even fill and store it from within Unity itself